# Which characters played the parts of the lineup discussed by Rusty and Daniel?

Tags: oceans-eleven

In planning the heist, Rusty names a number of roles that are going to be needed to pull off the job.

> Off the top of my head, I'd say you're looking at a **Boesky**, a **Jim Brown**, a **Miss Daisy**, two **Jethros**, and a **Leon Spinks.** Not to mention the biggest **Ella Fitzgerald** ever.

Which characters in the film lined up with these named roles?

Comment: This is a great question, it's one of those lines which flies past and you don't realise there's any more meaning to it!

Comment: is the "identify-this-movie" tag correct?

Comment: @dav1dsm1th: It is not. I have edited it out.

Comment: They are names for standard characters or items that they require to run a 'play'. Of course, the names make sense only to them as there is no international con artists encyclopedia.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wanted "identify this dialogue" tag !

Comment: I think this falls under 'plot explanation' (added)

Comment: Hmm...sounds good.

Comment: Ohh.... My Bad !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Source](http://adels-littlethings.blogspot.in/2010/03/oceans-11-cons-decryption.html)

> **The Boesky**: Saul playing Lymon Zherga, the whale who asks Benedict to
>   put his jewels, which are actually TNT, in the vault. if you've seen
>   *Wall Street* (with Michael Douglas), you'll know about Gordon Gekko, who was loosely based
>   on Ivan Boesky, a wall street trader who was involved in securities
>   fraud. That's where they got the idea of Lymon Zherga, an uber-rich
>   bankroller with insider information.
>
> **Jim Brown**: the fight between Frank Catton, who's impersonating a
>   blackjack dealer, and Linus Caldwell, who's impersonating a
>   representative from the Nevada Gaming Commission, a fight meant to
>   distract Benedict so Linus could pick Benedict's pocket, getting the
>   security codes to the vault. after watching enough ESPN classic games
>   with my dad, I learned all about Jim brown, who many people hail as
>   the greatest football player of all time. the fight between two
>   characters is called a Jim Brown because it's a physical
>   confrontation, one of the cornerstones upon which the sport of
>   football is built.
>
> **Miss Daisy**: references the SWAT truck the con men used as their
>   getaway car. *Driving Miss Daisy* (with Morgan Freeman) is a movie about a woman who has to
>   get a chauffeur to drive her around. Under the guise of the SWAT
>   truck, George, Brad, and the gang can escape without a hitch.
>
> **Two Jethros**: refers to the Malloy Brothers, Turk and Virgil,
>   the hillbilly, gear-headed types who are hired to
>   look after Miss Daisy. In the movie, they provide general two man work
>   like the distraction they pull with the balloons covering the security
>   camera on the casino floor so Livingston can get into the video
>   surveillance room.
>
> **Leon Spinks**: the distraction in the form of disrupting the boxing
>   match. An episode of *NCIS* had the director going
>   home to Chicago to investigate the death of his boxer friend. In the
>   episode, they mentioned this boxing match where Leon Spinks beat
>   Muhammad Ali, and it was a total upset that no one expected. No one
>   expected the power to go out in the middle of the match in the movie,
>   either, and it created absolute chaos, which was great for our con
>   artists.
>
> **Ella Fitzgerald**: the idea to loop a tape of a robbery over
>   Benedict's security system, a robbery which had actually been staged
>   the previous night as a distraction while the real robbery takes
>   place. It comes from a 1970s commercial for Memorex where a recording of Ella Fitzgerald's
>   voice breaks a glass, then the voice over says, "Is it live or is it
>   Memorex?". The concept is that Benedict doesn't know if the robbery
>   he's seeing is the robbery that's actually happening.

One more post regarding this on the [webz](http://news.moviefone.com/2011/12/07/25-things-you-didnt-know-about-oceans-11/):

> When Danny and Rusty (Pitt) first discuss the personnel they'll need to pull off the elaborate robbery, Rusty says, "Off the top of my
>   head, I'd say you're looking at a Boesky, a Jim Brown, a Miss Daisy,
>   two Jethros and a Leon Spinks, not to mention the biggest Ella
>   Fitzgerald ever!" The references don't become clear until much later,
>   when each conspirator's role is revealed. "Boesky," as in Wall Street
>   fraudster Ivan Boesky, is an apparent reference to Reiner's con man
>   Saul. "Jim Brown" (as in the 'Dirty Dozen' star) seems to refer to the
>   confrontational distraction provided by blacklisted blackjack dealer
>   Bernie Mac. "Miss Daisy" seems to be the getaway vehicle. The "two
>   Jethros" are the hillbilly-like gearheads played by Caan and Affleck.
>   "Leon Spinks" refers to the boxing match upset, caused in this case by
>   a power blackout. And "Ella Fitzgerald"? It has to do with the
>   videotaped robbery passed off as the real thing, a reference to
>   Fitzgerald's famous audiotape commercials in the 1970s in which a mere
>   recording of the jazz singer's high notes was enough to shatter a
>   glass, prompting the slogan, "Is it live, or is it Memorex?"

And this was confirmed by Steven Soderbergh

> "First of all, [screenwriter] Ted Griffin and I completely made the
>   terms up. We felt we had to come up with some funny, Damon
>   Runyon-esque turns of phrase that weren't arbitrary we did sit down
>   and think them out. So, Carl Reiner is the Boesky, as in Ivan, the
>   powerful, rich magnate, inside kind of guy. Jim Brown is the
>   confrontation Bernie Mac has with Matt Damon the 'don't mess with me
>   or you're in for it' moment. The two Jethros are Casey Affleck and
>   Scott Caan, the idea being 'we're going to need gear heads, car
>   fanatics...some people who are total hillbilly under-the-hood guys.' A
>   Leon Spinks is the disruption of the boxing match: A sporting event
>   with some controversy to it that's what Leon Spinks means to me. The
>   Miss Daisy association is driving; that was the SWAT van, a ruse
>   involving transportation. The Ella Fitzgerald is the tape of the fake
>   vault, which they're going to play back and have [Andy Garcia's
>   character] Benedict think it's live. 'Is it live, or is it Memorex?'"

Comment: Wow! Who'd had figured! And btw, excellent links.